# metrics needed - maximum memory allocation by Windows-Server-2012 for a .NET-program

Tags: performance, memory-management, .net-4.0, sandbox, windows-server-2012

I have a unique situation in relation to memory consumed by our product (built in .NET-Web) versus hardware-RAM.

The customer for whom the product is being deployed is having following configuration on PRODUCTION environment.

Hardware:

- [a] DUAL XEON X5570 2.93GHZ QUAD CORE CPU'S WITH 3.33GHZ TURBO,
  6.4GT/s QPI AND 8MB CACHE [b] 144GB RAM - MEMORY [c] 8x 600GB 10K 2.5" SAS HDD [d] SMART ARRAY P410i RAID CONTROLLER WITH BATTERY AND 256MB CACHE [e] 4x GIGABIT ETHERNET [f] DUAL 460W POWER SUPPLIES

Software (all in ONE box):

- [a] Windows Server 2012 - 64bit [b] .NET Framework 4.5 [c] SQL Server

2012 Enterprise Server edition

Now just because of the 144GB-RAM and high-volumen-HDD, our customer is expecting that the application should run "super-fast" and thus perform better.

The customer is a completely non-IT organization. It has already to explain to them, irrespective of however high the RAM/HDD gets increased, the Windows-OS ultimately has limitations to how much memory it can allocate to a program (via .NET-framework and SQL-Engine) so that a given .NET program would "execute" in a nice-contiguous, flat, unsegmented memory area.

They are NOT able to DIGEST this argument. So I have googled to see if there is any tech-article, blog or any such thing which explains on these lines, but without much success. Basically what needs to be conveyed through some web-article reference is : *no matter how much ever, you make your hardware better, the amount of memory allocated to an executing program is governed and limited by OS.*

Is there any MSDN link or Red-Gate-profiler analysis which gives some numbers to suggest the maXimum memory that gets allocated by Windows-64bit-Server-2012 to a given .NET-program's execution (or even a SQL-2012-store-procedure's execution).

For example -- This link http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory says the following for a 32-bit OS.
*"Each process in a multi-tasking OS runs in its own memory sandbox. This sandbox is the virtual address space, which in 32-bit mode is always a 4GB block of memory addresses."*

I am seeking something similar, as blog/msdn reference, for a 64-bit Windows-SERVER-2012 OS and IF that article(s) speaks more from a .NET-Framework-CLR perspective then, that would be "rivetting"...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems explaining to customer why its database does not run 2x faster when we added a secondary CPU and 2x more RAM.

The argument that closed the discussion: I does not slow down now when 2x more users login and work on the system.

I also know that for example native navision runs faster than sql version ... to some point.
But where more users works on the system (30-50+). SQL over native navision wins by not slowing down.

Also check Your SQL server memory settings. I try to assign myself a fixed amount of memory to SQL like for example 10GB of total 14GB. No matter how much you assign after some time if should eat everything :) Show them in task manager that it is using it :)

and if something runs slow on SQL - try to check the queries and do some database optimization. Maybe more well planned indexes will do the job ?